# Get key and value from an ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

How could I get the key and the value too from an ng-options element, if I load the data from an object, not from an array?

HTML:

```
    <select ng-model="select" ng-options="value for (key, value) in brand"></select>
    <pre>{{select}}</pre>
<!-- {{select.key}}, {{select.value}} -->
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.brand = {
        'a': 'alpha',
        'b': 'bravo',
        'c': 'charlie',
        'd': 'delta'
    };
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kreestian/mcy8yh7x/1/)

Thank in advance!

Comment: It's ok, but I want to GET the key and the value, after the user selected from the menu...

Comment: use `ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in brand"` as suggested. `key: {{select}}` and `value: {{brand[select]}}`.

Comment: It's look like the best solution. Thank you! The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kreestian/mcy8yh7x/12/